# Do you have to re-register a ZMQ socket with the poller?

Tags: sockets, zeromq

I'm opening a ZMQ socket and registering it with a poller as follows:

```
poll = zmq.Poller()
socket = context.socket(zmq.DEALER)
socket.setsockopt(zmq.IDENTITY, "identity")
socket.connect(url)
poll.register(socket, zmq.POLLIN)
```

Now I'd like to close and re-connect the socket to the same url. What is the best way to do this given that it is registered with the poller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
poll.unregister(socket)
socket.close()
```